# Pregnant in US in tourist visa without insurance

Tags: usa, money, insurance, tourist-visas, pregnancy

Me and my wife travel to the United states for tourist and business. My wife is 29 week pregnant and very healthy. First my plan was travel here a month and come back to give birth at home.

However, something unexpected happened and I have to stay another month. And by then it would be too late for my wife to travel so I am currently looking for a place that she can give birth here in the states.

Since we are tourist, we have travel insurance but it didnt cover the cost of child birth and we didnt think that we need.
So now I need you help, I am ok with paying the delivery out of my pocket. I have talk to hospital and they are quoting for me around 10k for a normal birth. I an looking for less as we still have many things to worry after her delivery, however I can still make it some how that but if any more than that it would be a trouble for me. I am looking for a way to cover a downside (c-section) or any complication. For example, insurance etc.

Medicaid would be my last resort and I really dont want to come to this unless I have no choice

This is my wife first time in the US and I tried to bring her here for a "babymoon" if you guys could help it would mean a lot to me. I dont want her to stress out over this.

Comment: This is insane.  If in this situation, get out ASAP.

Comment: This isn't a price shopping question and should be answered.

Comment: uru, have to tell you that one of the reasons you don't seem to be getting much sympathy is that this *looks* like an attempt to have your kid born in the US without being able to afford to pay for it.

Answer (score 4):

Buy a flight for your wife *right now* and have her give birth back at home. Don't rely on the American taxpayer to fund your child, no matter how attractive that option sounds.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that was an option, hopefully I can get another advice.

Comment: If anybody have a different way to look at it, I would be appriciated

Comment: @JonathanReez Americans got to fix the medical system so patients know the bill before they go for the procedure. Also, tone down and show some empathy, someone may have a valid situation to stay longer. http://www.nytimes.com/2013/05/08/business/hospital-billing-varies-wildly-us-data-shows.html

Comment: @AsadIqbal OP has been quoted $10k for a birth, which is very much reasonable by American standards. If they are unable to afford this, the only moral option is to fly back home. I'm sure a one-way ticket wouldn't be more than $1500.

Comment: @JonathanReez and he also mentioned that `I can still make it some how that but if any more than that it would be a trouble for me. ... Medicaid would be my last resort and I really dont want to come to this unless I have no choice`.  So we shouldn't assume that he is intentionally burdening American taxpayers.

Comment: @AsadIqbal Medicaid should indeed be a last resort, after OP has tried and failed to fly his wife out of the US. Giving birth can be extremely expensive in the States and no insurance would agree to cover it at this stage of pregnancy.

Comment: Someone on a B1/B2 visa will not get Medicaid anyway. So the OP is going to end up with a bill for whatever the birth costs. If they can't pay it then that is going to have an adverse effect on future visits to the US.